# How to calculate total cost of a transaction

Tags: gas-price

I've a transaction that consumed 276798 of gas, paid 900000000 (wei I think)

**Is the total cost `gasUsed x gasPrice`, right?**

Total = `249,118,200,000,000`‬  (wei I think)

So how many ether is ?

```
0.0002491182
```

Confirm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the total cost `gasUsed * gasPrice`?

Almost. It's `gasUsed * gasPrice + value`, where the latter indicates the amount of ether that you have passed (can be larger than 0 when executing a `payable` function, and must be 0 otherwise).

> Total = 249,118,200,000,000‬ (wei I think)

Yes, since both `gasPrice` and `value` are in wei, hence both components in the sum (`gasUsed * gasPrice` and `value`) are in wei, hence the entire formula (`gasUsed * gasPrice + value`) is in wei.

> So how many ether - 0.0002491182?

- Take 249,118,200,000,000‬
- Remove the commas in order to get 249118200000000‬
- Add 3 zeros on the left in order to get an 18-digit number: 000249118200000000‬
- Add '0.' in order to divide that number by 10^18 and get 0.000249118200000000‬
- Remove all the zeros on the right in order to "clean it up" and get 0.0002491182

So yes, it is 0.0002491182 ether.